# jQuery UI Drag 'n' Drop Ghosting Effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, scriptaculous

I'm trying to mimic the "ghosting" functionality from Scriptaculous with jQuery UI. I've found the demo and could get DnD working, but the option to ghost an item as it's being dragged seems to be missing.

All this does is: When you drag an item, it remains in place until dropped but you get a semi-transparent copy which follows the mouse.

Is this possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, look at this demo :
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback

I think the one you need is the semi-transparent clone.

The draggable UI property involved is 'helper'.

Comment: They tend to squirrel away gems like this sometimes. There are demos for every piece of what I need - Draggable, droppable, sortable lists which fire a PostBack. Thanks.